# Css initial caps

Tags: html, css, firefox, text

I have a problem with initial caps(first letter big).

```
.article {
    text-align:justify;
    text-wrap: unrestricted;
    -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count:3;
}

.article:first-letter {
    font-size:38px;
    float:left;
    line-height: 38px;
}
.article:first-line { line-height: 100%; }
```

First: In firefox the letter is moved up like a supertext. I tried using `vertical-align` with no succes. I noticed it only renders like that in firefox.

*Second: I want the caps to be 40px high(they are 38px right now). When I add 2 extra pixels, the third line in small text is indented too. Why? Is it to make space for any unusual letters that fall below the text (like j)?*

Comment: Putting in a J at first and increasing both font size and line height to 40 pixels only indents 2 lines.  I'm running firefox v21.0

Comment: Dharman, if you feel that your solution will help others, will you post your corrections as an answer below and mark it as "accepted" when allowed by the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just tweak the margin of your `:first-letter` pseudo-class.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwHas/6/)

Comment: Still creates browser differences sadly. The position of a single letter when pulled out of flow layout with a float isn't really standardized.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some padding to the first letter seems to pull it back into line - http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/aBYQx/

```
.article {
    text-align:justify;
    text-wrap: unrestricted;
    -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count:3;
}

.article:first-letter {
    font-size:40px;
    float:left;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:.125em 

}
.article:first-line { line-height: 100%; }
```

as for the added space I'd assume that it is to accommodate descenders

Comment: Still has differences between Chrome and FF. As noted elsewhere the positioning after float isn't quite standardized.